# How to resolve ambiguous implicit values in Scala for parsing JSON in Play Json?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, spray, circe

I'm getting an error

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:45: error: ambiguous implicit values:

both getter _ewriter in module class ScalaFiddle of type => 
json.this.Reads[ScalaFiddle.this.SportJSON]

and getter _jwriter in module class ScalaFiddle of type => 
json.this.Reads[ScalaFiddle.this.Score]

match expected type json.this.Reads[T]
val result: Soccer=Json.fromJson(t2).get
                              ^
```

Anyone know what this means or any hints on what to read to resolve?

In general, I've also tried Circe and Spray (no luck either), do these macros rely on the field names being exactly the same as the json field names?

Thanks!

Code in question:
https://scalafiddle.io/sf/BOUqhMz/0

Edit:
Json in question, thanks!
https://pastebin.com/usScQWd7

Comment: Please post the json file also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `Json.fromJson[Soccer](t2).get`

I did not understand your schema but that is how you pass the implicit

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/BOUqhMz/3